# Responsive pointing arrow in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, responsive

I need a stepper that looks like the following:

[when on first tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO3Bh.png)

[when on second tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Zxx.png)

I want it to be responsive so that it works on differing screen sizes.

I'm using MUI stepper component to create a custom stepper like in this Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-9rwm86

This gives me something roughly like the above, but it's not responsive. The layout gets messed up if I change the screen size or even the size of the container element.

How can I make it responsive? Is there a built-in stepper like the one I want in MUI?

Comment: Please share a working code in codesandbox. So, We can help you out.

Comment: @MaulikPatel I've shared a sandbox link.

Comment: I will try to forked your sandbox and get back to you as soon as I can. Meanwhile, here is the reference you can use: https://mui-treasury.com/styles/tabs/